# Relative Todd class of projective bundle fibration

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $E\to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $r+1$ over a complex manifold $X$. Denote by
$$\pi: \mathbb{P}(E)\to X$$
the projectivization of $E$.

I would like to compute the relative Todd class of $\pi$, that is the Todd class $td(\pi)\in H^*(\mathbb{P}(E))$ of the fibers $\pi^{-1}(x)\simeq \mathbb{P}^r$. Is it simply the pull back of $td(\mathbb{P}^r)$ by the second projection of the trivializations
$$\pi^{-1}(U)\simeq U\times \mathbb{P}^r$$
or something a bit more involved?

Comment: What is the Todd class of a subvariety?

Comment: @abx the td class of its tangent bundle

Comment: If you mean the Todd class of the relative tangent bundle $T_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X}$, this is easy: from the Euler exact sequence $0\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_{\mathbb{P}(E)}\rightarrow \pi ^*E(1)\rightarrow T_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X}\rightarrow 0$, you get $\operatorname{Todd}T_{\mathbb{P}(E)/X} =\operatorname{Todd}\pi^*E(1) ).\  $ ($E$ or $E^*$ depending on your definition of $\Bbb{P}(E)$).

Comment: @abx could you give a bit more details how to obtain the relative Euler sequence please?

Comment: See [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36658/which-is-the-correct-generalization-of-euler-sequence-to-the-projectivization-of).

Comment: @abx Is there a way to compute (somehow) $Todd(\pi^*E(1))$?

Comment: Yes, use the [splitting principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_principle).

Comment: @abx sorry to ask further, could you sketch how so?

Comment: The splitting principle tells you that to compute the Todd class of a vector bundle $E$, it suffices to do it when   $E=\bigoplus L_i$ with $\operatorname{rk}L_i=1 $, so that  $\operatorname{Todd}E =\prod\operatorname{Todd} L_i$, then to express the result in terms of the Chern classes of $E$.